# SWIG: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found

Tags: python-3.x, module, compiler-errors, compilation, swig

When I try to compile, it tells me that I am missing the `<Python.h>` file.
How can I get the `<Python.h>` file ? I can't compile my stuff without it.

I'm on MacOS Version 10.12.6

Here's a screenshot of my terminal:

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your include path for Python headers looks wrong.

You have `-I/usr/`**`bin`**`/python3.7`. I'm pretty sure even on MacOS that `bin` is wrong, since that's the Python interpreter itself. It does however depend where and how you've got this Python version what the correct path would be. Likely it's `-I/usr/include/python3.7`, but to be sure you probably want to use something like `find / -name 'Python.h` and see what's currently installed on your system.